# How to get the url variable in Django?

Tags: django, url

I have something like that in my `views.py`:

```
class CommentMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MenuMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = Comments.objects.filter(post=xxxxxxxxxxxxx).order_by('-pub_date')
        return context
...

class PostDetailView(CommentMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Post

PostDetail = PostDetailView.as_view()
PostList = PostList.as_view()
```

and a fragment of `comment.html`:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
    <article class="uk-comment">
    <header class="uk-comment-header">
        <img class="uk-comment-avatar" src="{%gravatar_url comment.email%}" alt="Avatar">
        <h4 class="uk-comment-title">{{comment.author}}</h4>
        <div class="uk-comment-meta">Dodano dnia {{comment.pub_date}}</div>
    </header>
    <div class="uk-comment-body">{{comment.content}}</div>
</article>
```

Fragment of `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[\w\-_]+)/$', 'page.views.PostDetail', name='post-detail'),
```

I want replace the `xxxxxxxxxxxxx` by the post on that  page. The url format is looking like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/post/my-post-name/
```

Comment: You can just do `self.request.POST`

Comment: What is the entry in urls.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DetailView` stores object in **self.object**.
And in `get_context_data` you can use it in filter:

```
context['comments'] = Comments.objects.filter(post=self.object).order_by('-pub_date')
```